# How do I find the mean value of a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

New to coding and don't have my friend to help me atm. My current question - I have a dictionary of dictionaries with a mixture of values and 'masked'. I need to find the mean of all of the values that are not masked. Below is the code that I've created in order to get a dictionary of observations:

```
path_2 = "/Volumes/TRANSEND/Thesis Files/Utqiagvik Obs Ceilometer/"

#fn = '/Volumes/TRANSEND/Thesis Files/Oliktok Obs/oli30smplcmask1zwangM1.c1.20191001.000006.custom.nc'
#sd = nc.Dataset(fn)

obs = {} # largest dictionary with all of the days and then observations. Pass through a day and an hour to get an obs

for file in os.listdir(path_2):
    
    obs_day = {} # secondary dictionary for each day. Includes all the hours. Pass through an hour to get an obs
    index = hour = 0

    hour_indices = []

# or file == "OliktokObs.py" add back in if you go back to oliktok
    if file == "OliktokObs.py" or file == ".DS_Store" or file == "nsaceilC1.b1.20190930.000000.custom.nc" or file == "nsaceilC1.b1.20191103.000013.custom.nc":
        prev_file = file
        continue
    
    fn = "/Volumes/TRANSEND/Thesis Files/Utqiagvik Obs Ceilometer/" + file
    
    sd = nc.Dataset(fn)
    
# This creates a preamble to be able to extract the day from the filename
    preamble_3 = 'b1.'
    index_3 = file.index(preamble_3)
    obs_date = file[index_3 + len(preamble_3) : index_3 + len(preamble_3) + 8]

# This adds the observations for each hour into the corresponding dictionary. Averages the cloud base ten minutes before and ten minutes after the hour.  
    for time in sd['time']:

        if int(time) % 3600 < 30 and hour != 24:
            clear_count = 0
            hour_indices.append(index)
            average_value = []
            if hour == 0:
                sd_prev = nc.Dataset("/Volumes/TRANSEND/Thesis Files/Utqiagvik Obs Ceilometer/" + prev_file)
                for i in range(20):
                    if not np.ma.is_masked(sd_prev['first_cbh'][len(sd_prev['first_cbh']) - 20 + i]):
                        average_value.append(sd_prev['first_cbh'][len(sd_prev['first_cbh']) - 20 + i])
                    if not np.ma.is_masked(sd['first_cbh'][i]):
                        average_value.append(sd['first_cbh'][i])
            else:
                for i in range(40):
                    if not np.ma.is_masked(sd['first_cbh'][index - 20 + i]):
                        average_value.append(sd['first_cbh'][index - 20 + i])
            
            if len(average_value) < 20: # wtf does this line/chunk of code mean i totally forgot
                obs_day[hour] = np.ma.masked
            else:
                obs_day[hour] = np.asarray(average_value).mean()

             
            #print("Day: " + str(obs_date) + ", Hour: " + str(hour) +  ", Cloud Base: " + str(sd['cloud_base'][index]*1000))
            hour += 1
            
        index += 1
        
    obs[obs_date] = obs_day
    prev_file = file

print(obs)
```

And below is a sample of what is output. I have output for every day of Oct 2019:

```
    {'20191001': {0: 163.0, 1: 271.75, 2: 1933.0, 3: 393.0, 4: 726.5, 5: 808.91895, 6: 639.4595, 7: 634.25, 8: 763.8461, 9: 745.64105, 10: 537.75, 11: 539.25, 12: 561.75, 13: 563.25, 14: 387.75, 15: 325.25, 16: 324.25, 17: 444.75, 18: 444.25, 19: 286.0, 20: 282.5, 21: 249.25, 22: 253.25, 23: 691.94446}, 
     '20191002': {0: masked, 1: masked, 2: 668.0, 3: 668.0, 4: 907.0, 5: 907.75, 6: 849.0, 7: 846.0, 8: 718.5, 9: 721.5, 10: 832.25, 11: 831.5, 12: 5189.048, 13: 5122.0, 14: 5680.0, 15: 5677.5, 16: 665.1852, 17: 664.61536, 18: masked, 19: masked, 20: masked, 21: masked, 22: masked, 23: masked}, 
     '20191003': {0: 96.5, 1: 89.52381, 2: 77.57576, 3: 77.57576, 4: masked, 5: masked, 6: masked, 7: masked, 8: masked, 9: masked, 10: masked, 11: masked, 12: masked, 13: masked, 14: masked, 15: masked, 16: 80.26316, 17: 80.789474, 18: 79.375, 19: 79.09091, 20: 103.25, 21: 102.25, 22: masked, 23: masked}}
```

The largest dictionary is called 'obs' and I pass through a date to get the corresponding dictionary for that day. The secondary dictionary is called 'obs_day' and I pass through a forecast hour to get the cloud base height for that hour on that day.

My goal is to try to calculate the average of all of the values that are not masked so that I can see what the average cloud base height is for the entire month (when there is a cloud base). Are there any suggestions of how average all of the values that are not masked?

I've tried:

```
    for date in obs:
        res = statistics.mean(list(obs_day.values()))
        print(res)
```

And gotten:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [11], in <cell line: 1>()
          1 for date in obs:
    ----> 2     res = statistics.mean(list(obs_day.values()))
          3     print(res)
    
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I've also just tried

```
res = {day: statistics.mean(v for v in data.values() if v != "masked") for day, data in obs.items()}
```

and gotten

```
StatisticsError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 res = {day: statistics.mean(v for v in data.values() if v != "masked") for day, data in obs.items()}

Input In [5], in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 res = {day: statistics.mean(v for v in data.values() if v != "masked") for day, data in obs.items()}

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/statistics.py:315, in mean(data)
    313 n = len(data)
    314 if n < 1:
--> 315     raise StatisticsError('mean requires at least one data point')
    316 T, total, count = _sum(data)
    317 assert count == n

StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point
```

Comment: What is `obs_day`? Are you _entirely sure_ that it's a dictionary and not some other data structure?

Comment: Try `res = {day: statistics.mean(v for v in data.values() if v != "masked") for day, data in obs.items()}` (without the loop).